# WebApp for container is trying to pull from wrong container registry

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I've tried setting up WebApp for Containers in Azure and selecting a private container registry pointing to an Azure Container Registry in another subscription but the webapp tries to pull the image from `registry-1.docker.io` instead of my private one. Can anyone see what I am missing?
[image]

Comment: Any more updates for the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the image name. You need to set the image name as `yourACR.azurecr.io/image:tag` if you use a private registry and point to an Azure Container Registry. All the docker images are pulled from the registry `docker.io` in default. For the private registry, you must set the registry name before the image name.

Comment: Thank you, I was facing the same issue trying to use the GitHub Container Registry. The configuration screen really should make it clearer, and I'm quite irritated that it just keeps plugging away at a third party (Docker Hub) rather than telling you that your configuration is wrong.